# kafkaconnect - delete document via mongodb sink connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have used kafka-connect to write the data from topic to mongodb. I am able to create and update the record via curl command configuration. I could not delete the document. I have written the configuration like below,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"test-testing-delete7",
 "config":{"topics":"testing",
 "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max":"1",
 "connection.uri":"mongodb://localhost:27017",
 "database":"flower",
 "collection":"testing",
 "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list":"id",
 "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
 "writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.DeleteOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
}}' localhost:8083/connectors
```

Using this configuration, I am able to delete the field which are present under that id. I would like to delete the document completely. How can I proceed?

Comment: Does mongo have data matching id: valuePassed?

Comment: What exact data are you producing to Kafka? You should be able delete documents using tombstone records for the document ID.

Comment: yes, I can able to delete when i delete the data by producing the message by producer. {"id":"1"}. But, it will delete the data inside the document. I would like to delete the document what configuration should i give?